# Guia definitiva de conversión de tipos en Java

Tags: java, conversión-de-tipos, tipos

Guia definitiva de conversión de tipos en *Java*

- Convertir `String` a `Integer`
- Convertir `Integer` a `String`
- Convertir `char` a `String`
- Convertir `String` a `char`
- Convertir `String` a `Double`
- Convertir `Double` a `String`
- Convertir `String` a `Float`
- Convertir `Float` a `String`
- Convertir `String` a `Boolean`
- Convertir `Boolean` a `String`

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## String a Integer

```
Integer entero = Integer.valueOf(cadena);
// o
int entero = Integer.parseInt(cadena);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
Integer a = Integer.valueOf("900");
// o
int b = Integer.parseInt("900");
```

## Integer a String

```
String cadena = Integer.toString(entero);
// o
String cadena = String.valueOf(entero);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
String importe = Integer.toString(900);
// o
int entero = 900;
String mensaje = String.valueOf(entero);
```

## char a String

```
String cadena = Character.toString(char);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
char codigo = 'A';
String cadena = Character.toString(codigo);
```

## String a char

```
char caracter = cadena.charAt(0); //Solo primer caracter
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
String codigo= "E";
char caracter = cadena.charAt(0);
```

## String a Double

```
double doble = Double.parseDouble(cadena);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
double doble = Double.parseDouble("900.1");
```

## Double a String

```
String cadena = String.valueOf(doble);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
double totalDoble = 900.5;
String totalString = String.valueOf(doble);
```

## String a Float

```
float flotante = Float.parseFloat(cadena);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
float importe = Float.parseFloat("900.5");
```

## Float a String

```
String cadena = Float.toString(flotante);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
String total = Float.toString(900.1f);
```

## String a Boolean

```
Boolean boolean = Boolean.valueOf(cadena);
// o
boolean boolean = Boolean.parseBoolean(cadena);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
Boolean boolean = Boolean.valueOf("true");
// o
boolean boolean = Boolean.parseBoolean("false");
```

## Boolean a String

```
String cadena = String.valueOf(b);
// o
String cadena = Boolean.toString(b);
```

*Ejemplo:*

```
boolean b = true;
String cadena = String.valueOf(b);
// o
boolean b = false;
String cadena = Boolean.toString(b);
```

Answer (score 7):

> Para hacer la siguiente operación necesitaremos hacer uso de la clase
>   `Integer` y de su método `"parseInt"` de la siguiente manera:

```
    String numCadena = "1";

int numEntero = Integer.parseInt(numCadena);
```

> ¿Qué problemas podemos tener? pues que la cadena no sólo contenga
>   números sino que venga con espacios.
>
> Si los espacios vienen al princio o al final, con un simple trim
>   bastará para eliminarlos, por ejemplo `("1")`

```
numCadena.trim();
```

> Si tenemos espacio entre los números deberíamos usar el método

```
replaceAll (" 1 3 45 6")
numCadena.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

> Una vez realiazdos estos sencillos pasos podremos trabajar con los
>   números enteros.

**PASAR UN INT A STRING (DE ENTERO A CADENA)**

> Para pasar de un tipo básico a un objeto String tenemos varias
>   posibilidades, por un lado, si eres un artesano, puedes simplemente
>   concatenar a tu entero una cadena vacía:

```
    int numEntero = 4;

String numCadena= numEntero+"";
```

> La forma correcta de realizar esta operación sería invocando al método
>   `valueOf` de la clase `String`

```
int numEntero = 4;

String numCadena= String.valueOf(numEntero);
```

> Otra forma correcta de hacerlo sería utilizando el método toString del
>   objeto Integer de la siguiente manera:

```
String numCadena= Integer.toString(numEntero);
```