# Error en java de casteo

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola gente de stack tengo un problema y es el siguiente:

Quiero traer los datos de mi **LISTA** (`JPanel`) a unos `JTextField`, y lo estuve haciendo con el evento `ListSelection`, el problema es que solo sé traer los datos de tipo `String` y no los de tipo `int`, ni tampoco el tipo `Date`, intente hacerle un casteo pero ninguno de los que probé me dieron resultado, les dejo un ejemplo de como traigo el dato de tipo `String` y me funciona, pero el de tipo `int` y `Date` no me trae los datos por un error de casteo. Solamente me falta castear de forma correcta, y **con algunos ejemplos de google ninguno me dio resultado**, espero que se me entienda y me puedan ayudar.

```
private void listContratoValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                          
  // ITEM ACTUAL SELECCIONADO
  if(!this.listContrato.isSelectionEmpty()) {
    // obtengo el item seleccionado
    Contrato contratos = (Contrato) this.listContrato.getSelectedValue();

    //ASIGNAR VALORES
    this.labelId.setText(contratos.getIdContrato().toString());
    this.txtLugar.setText(contratos.getLugar());
    this.txtFecha.getText();
    this.txtCantidad.getText();
    this.txtTotal.getText();
  }
}
```

Me retornan los datos de tipo `String` como el Lugar, solamente, me falta retornar la cantidad y la fecha que son de tipo `Date`, probé casteando, al final con `.toString()` pero no tuve resultados, saludos.

---

Probé con:

```
this.txtFecha.getText(contratos.getFecha().toString());
this.txtCantidad.getText(contratos.getCantidad().toString());
```

---

También probé:

```
 precio = Double.parseDouble(this.txtPrecio.getText());
 String p = String.valueOf(this.txtPrecio.getText());
```

Pero sigo sin poder traer mis datos de tipo `int` ni `Date`.

Saludos! espero respuestas!

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacerlo al revés? Es decir, declara e inicializa todo en String y luego al obtenerlo castealo cada uno a su tipo original. Por ejemplo de String a int, de String a date, etc. Espero que te sirva de ayuda, un saludo. Te dejo un enlace de esta misma comunidad que tiene una guía de casteo de tipos de datos, échale un vistazo. [Enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1487/guia-definitiva-de-conversi%C3%B3n-de-tipos-en-java)

Comment: Pero ¿la clase `Contrato` no tiene *getters*  también para esos datos? Viendo que en los otros usas *getters*  de `Contrato`, ¿por qué para la fecha, la cantidad, etc no usas también *getters*  de la clase?

Comment: El error puede venir por algún carácter extraño del this.txtPrecio.getText() que obviamente no puede ser transformado a double, o que por ejemplo le falta la , o el punto etc.

Comment: ¿Cuando haces `this.txtFecha.getText(contratos.getFecha().toString());` 
 qué error te da o que resultado obtienes?

Answer (score 1):

Debes meterlo en una variable. puesto que no tengo tus clases te pongo mi ejemplo.
yo tengo mi clase paciente que tinee

```
private int edad 
private String nombre 
private int codigo paciente
```

. En el Jframe tengo unos textfiel donde aparece los nombres la edad etc. 
Yo le hago un paseo normal y corrienote para crear el Paciente debo de setear lo datos de sus clase y lo hago asi

```
  private void bntAgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        Cita nuevaCita;
        String nombrePaciente = jNombre.getText();
        String especialidad = cmbEspecialidad.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String nombreMedico = cmbDoctor.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Date fechaD = (Date) jSFecha.getValue();
        int codPac = Integer.parseInt(cmbPaciente.getSelectedItem().toString());
        int edadNum = Integer.parseInt(jEdad.getText());
        Paciente nPaciente = new Paciente(codPac, nombrePaciente, edadNum);
```